# PHP imagick equivalent of -define png:color-type=6

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, png, imagick

I'm needing to save my PNG files with a different color type so ffmpeg can process them correctly. I'm using the PHP library for imagemagick, and I'm trying to figure out how to implement the following (command line) in imagick PHP:

`-define png:color-type=6`

Answer (score 2):

Found it...

`$imagick->setOption('png:color-type', 6);`